# UICollectionView: How to define a UICollectionViewLayout that supports horizontally and vertically scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

At the moment I'm trying to create an `UICollectionView`, that should display a simple `excel-like-spreadsheet`, with `rows` and `columns`. This should be an easy task with `UICollectionViews`, I believed. And I really would like to do the implementation in `UICollectionView`, not in any `grid framework`.

But at the moment I'm hanging a little bit. What I've figured out is, that I unfortunately can't use a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, because this only supports `scrolling` in **either** `horizontally` or `vertically` direction. But I need `scrolling` in both directions.

Therefore **I have to use a `UICollectionViewLayout`**, but for this I didn't find good examples, how to use it. Has anyone of you an example, how to subclass an `UICollectionViewLayout` to support `rows` and `columns`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` definitely can't - "The grid layout scrolls along one axis only, either horizontally or vertically."

It is a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`. Seems like you could create your own subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` and scroll in both directions.

What do you mean by page, you want to do paging like a `scrollview`? I'm wondering about using UICollectionViewFlowLayout in a `UICollectionView` for vertical scrolling, inside a `UIScrollView` for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Yes, I know already, that I have to use UICollectionViewLayout instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayout... this I've posted already in the initial question.

So your comment did absolutely not answer the question, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

I've added an example of using a custom layout to implement a simple horizontal & vertical scrolling grid here https://github.com/neildavis/MyCollectionView

My example uses PSTCollectionView since I needed iOS 5 support, but it's API compatible with built in UICollectionView. (Actually it uses the compatibility classes (PSUICollectionView etc) provided to ensure it uses a UICollectionView on iOS 6 and falls back to using PSTCollectionView etc on iOS 5.) Just remove the 'PS' prefix on these to revert to iOS 6 only UIKit implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I needed something similar. I created a Custom CollectionViewLayout.

https://github.com/akashraje/BidirectionalCollectionViewLayout

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me, though had to be careful with the spelling of the component as it isn't automatically picked up by Xcode, and a small typo had me going around in circles for ages.

Comment: Great! With this source you can also implement a selection for a row of items.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer that doesn't require dissecting a 3 sample projects**

In your UICollectionViewLayout subclass:

1. Implement `-(CGSize)[collectionViewContentSize]` and return a size larger in height and width than the `UICollectionView`'s size. (Accessible via: `self.collectionView.frame.size`)
2. Calculate layout for your `UICollectionViewCell`s within the content size rather than the frame size.

Note: Make sure scrolling is enabled in the UICollectionView. (It's on by default.)