# Scroll UICollectionView on both sides horizontal as well as vertical

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview

How to scroll UICollectionView on both sides horizontally and vertically. How is it possible, please guide.
Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me what happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266170/uicollectionview-how-to-define-a-uicollectionviewlayout-that-supports-horizonta

Comment: A UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView, look at the docs for that

Comment: I found some answers for this question in SO itself. Have a look at those.. [View with continuous scroll; both horizontal and vertical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549233/view-with-continuous-scroll-both-horizontal-and-vertical?answertab=oldest#tab-top) [MyCollectionView](https://github.com/neildavis/MyCollectionView)

Comment: Have you checked my Answer ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Discussion in RWForums for [How to scroll UICollectionView in any direction ?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=29811)

> "The grid layout scrolls
>   along one axis only, either horizontally or vertically."

Check out the two-part tutorial from **Ray Wenderlich** that uses a table view, but it demonstrates how to have cells within a section scroll horizontally, while the sections scroll vertically :

**1)** [Part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

**2)** [Part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

GoodLuck!!!

Comment: ya it is using uitableview and i have done on uicollectionview.

Comment: @iPhoneProgrammatically : You can take the Basic Concept from there and modify it according to your requirement. :)

Comment: That's ok but it is totally different from done in uicollectionview i have already implemented the maximum functionality on this so can't change anything now and it's totally different from this.

Comment: but i will try later on if necessary.